# ASP.net Core MVC 2.0 Passing FormEditModel from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello, i am doing a simple blog using Microsoft asp.net MVC Core 2.0 for a school project and have encountered a problem while implementing CRUD operations for Articles. More precisely i have an issue only with the edit article method.
Here is my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateModelState]
     public async Task<IActionResult> EditArticle(ArticleEditServiceModel parameter)
        {
            parameter.Title = this.html.Sanitize(parameter.Title);
            parameter.Content = this.html.Sanitize(parameter.Content);

            //var user = this.userManager.GetUserName(User.Identity.Name)

            await this.articles.EditAsync(parameter.Id, parameter.Title, parameter.Content);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

And here is my service "EditAsync" method:

```
public async Task<bool> EditAsync(int id, string title, string content)
        {
            var article = await this.db.Articles.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (article == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            article.Title = title;
            article.Content = content;

            await this.db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
```

The View:

```
@model ArticleEditServiceModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Article";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="Article" asp-action="EditArticle"  asp-route-parameter=@Model method="post"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content"></label>
                <input asp-for="Content"  required class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <a asp-controller="Article" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
            <button type="submit" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-success">Edit Article</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
}
```

It finds the correct article by Id and gives me the two input fields where i can edit the text, but when i click the submit button there are no changes applied to the Article. I tried debugging and found out that the view send a null model to the controller post method. I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code so i figured i should ask more experienced developers for input.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried debugging and found out that the view send a null model to the
>   controller post method.

I believe the view sends correct request but error happens during model binding on server side.

To fix the problem, you should add `[FromBody]` attribute for `ArticleEditServiceModel` parameter in controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditArticle([FromBody] ArticleEditServiceModel parameter)
```

`FromBody` attribute instructs ASP.NET Core framework that action parameter should be deserialized from request body with media type formatter based on `Content-Type` http header. Check [this article](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) for details, it explains the difference in model binding between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core MVC.

Answer (score 0):

you should take out asp-route-id=@Model.Id from the form cuz you send the model directly to EditArticle. Create one input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" class="form-control" And will work.